# Algolia autocomplete - how to display autocomplete suggestions in English?

Tags: autocomplete, algolia

Is it possible to have Algolia's autocomplete suggestions display ONLY in English? At the moment the city, country displays in English, however, suburbs and municipalities etc (administrative) displays in native language of each country. It is really annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `configure` on your places instance once it's created:

```
const placesInstance = places({
  appId: 'YOUR_PLACES_APP_ID',
  apiKey: 'YOUR_PLACES_API_KEY',
  container: document.querySelector('#demo'),
});

placesInstance.configure({
  language: 'en'
});
```

The docs for [the language option](https://community.algolia.com/places/documentation.html#api-options-language) indeed mention that by default, the browser's language will be used.